# Passing this by reference (ref this)

Tags: c#

Consider the following code snippet( written in a Windows Form Application):

```
public partial class Form1
{
    ....
    public void Caller()
    {
        Form1 myRef = this;
        Change(ref this)    //--> won't compile because *this* is read-only
        Change(ref myRef);  //--> compiles but doesn't work.
    }
    ....

    public void Change(ref Form1 theRef)
    {
        theRef = new Form1();
        theRef.Text = "I am a new form";
    }
}
```

Passing `this` by reference is not allowd. That's ok and sensible. But why passing `this` indirectly as shown above is not working? As I know if a parameter is passed by reference any assignment in the called method is reflected out to the caller method. Why isn't it working here?

**Update to make the question clear**

1- I am not struggling to accomplish anything special. I am just trying to test `ref`.

2- The reason why I misunderstood the `ref` is that I totally forgot `Form1 myRef = this` actually **copies** the address of underlying `Form1` object to `myRef`; so `myRef` variable has nothing to do with `this` except that both of them points to the same object.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Of course the second call is working, it's just modifying the `myRef` **variable** in `Caller`. You cannot change `this` for a reference type, period.

Comment: Change this indirectly is not posible, but myRef value will be changed

Comment: You're changing a completely separate reference... thats why the second one works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works as it should. The problem is that this is not the same as what you are expecting.

```
Form1 myRef = this;
var b1 = object.ReferenceEquals(myRef, this); // true
Change(ref myRef);
var b2 = object.ReferenceEquals(myRef, this); // false
```

So the value of `myRef` changes. That the change does not propagate to `this` should be expected; after making the assignment `myRef` and `this` are totally separate variables. C# does not have "ref variables", so it couldn't be any other way (even if it had, reassigning `this` in this manner would never be allowed).

Answer (score 3):

Using `myRef` does actually work, after the method call it will in fact be a reference to a new Form instance. It will also have the `Text` property changed, but you will not see anything because you are not displaying your new Form instance. It is **not** the same instance as your original form (`this`), so that form will not be changed in any way.

If you want to change a property of the form you can do it like this:

```
public void Change(Form1 theRef)
{
    theRef.Text = "I am a new form";
}
```

which can be called like so:

```
Change(this);
```

But you cannot create a "new form" to replace the existing one like that. Perhaps you should consider having some sort of `Reset()` function, that clears the form as you need.

If you really need to replace the current form, then you will need some sort of "parent" that can manage the original form.

Answer (score 1):

Because you cannot assign a value to `this`.

Comment: ... *in a reference type*. Although changing it in a value type is allowed, it sometimes doesn't do what you think it will do, so it should've been disallowed there as well.

Comment: Not *passing `this` by reference*, but you can assign a value to `this`, sure.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it works. I assume you expect your current form to change, this however won't work like this. What your code does is changing the content of the reference you pass. It does not destroy/replace your current form.

What you need to do is something like

- Create (new) a Form and Open it (.Show or .ShowDialog)
- Destroy the current Form (.Close)

Answer (score 0):

In reference types, `this` is read-only, there's no way around that.

Your second call does indeed work, but it changes the `myRef` variable to refer to a new form. `this` still refers to the original form, since you cannot change that anyway.

This answer is just a more full response to a comment above, to clarify that `this` is not read-only *everywhere in C#/.NET*.

In a value type, you can assign a new value to `this`, but you still cannot pass `this` by reference, so your code still won't work.

However, here's a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) example of assigning a new value to `this`, which "works" in a value type.

```
void Main()
{
    Test t = new Test(17);
    t.Dump();
    t.StrangeMutation();
    t.Dump();
}

public struct Test
{
    public readonly int Value;

    public Test(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public void StrangeMutation()
    {
        this = new Test(42);
    }
}
```

Notice that the `Value` field is read-only, so there appears to be no way that the field should change its value, however the output of the above program is that first the field has the value 17, the next time we check it it has the value 42.

This, however, **only** works in value types. It does not work with reference types, and you cannot pass by reference either.